# Concatenation while instantiating a class

Tags: php, class

I'd like to instantiate a model (in Zend Framework) using a generic way. I have `$type` variable which contains the name of the model. I'd like to write something like this

```
$db = new Admin_Model_{$type}();
```

But it doesn't work, Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the **entire** class name as a string in order for this to work:

```
$model = 'Admin_Model_' . $type;
$db = new $model();
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I wrote `$this->db = new {'Admin_Model_' . $this->type}();` and received `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' `